# Getting unknown protocol error when trying to POST to endpoint

Tags: java, http, post, request, endpoint

I am trying to connect to an endpoint using a post method however I keep getting the following error:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: localhost
at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:634)
at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:523)
at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:470)
at endpointtest.endpoint(endpointtest.java:23)
at main.main(endpoint.java:66)
```

I would expect my code to return the response based on the post request however that is not the case. Below is my code:

```
public class endpointtest {

    public String endpoint(String urlStr, String username) {

        final StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            //creating the connection
            URL url = new URL(urlStr);

            HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "Value");
            connection.connect();


            //builds the post body, adds parameters
            final DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            //out.writeBytes(toJSON(globalId)); 
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            //Reading the response
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String inputline;

            while ((inputline = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputline);
            }
            in.close();

            connection.getResponseCode();
            connection.disconnect();

        } catch (final Exception ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(" error ");
        }

        return response.toString();


    }

}
class main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        endpointtest ep = new endpointtest();
        ep.endpoint("localhost:8080/endpoint","123");
    }
}
```

Why is this error occuring? Forgive me if there are basic errors, I am new to web dev

Comment: http == protocol

Comment: when you are using "localhost" then you should use http not https. and also change your content-type value.

Comment: @priyranjan confused as to what the content-type should be changed to

Comment: have a look on this link https://www.javatpoint.com/content-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have not included protocol(`http`/`https`) in your URL string.

Change it to `ep.endpoint("http://localhost:8080/endpoint", "123");` 
and it should work.